# Excel: whatif when there are both positive and negative numbers in a column

Tags: excel

this might be a very simple one to answer, however I've been struggling with this for hours, using IF, AND & OR principally, and would benefit from your collective help...

- Col.A has either negative balances, or zeros.
- Col.B has either positive balances, negative balances or zeros and is D+E.
- Col.C is the sum of A+B unless this total exceeds 0, in which case
  C=0
- Col.D is a sum total column and is either the inverse of A or zero
- Col.E is also a sum total column and is whatever's left **after**
  doing B-D.

Hopefully the following criteria are useful:

If B>A, then C=zero, D should be the inverse of A and the remainder of B shown in E (i.e. B-A). So D & E analyse-out B depending on whether B>A.

I.e., if A=(100) & B=250, then C=0, D=100 and E=150.

And, if A=0 & B=250, then C=0, D=0 and E=250

If B < A then C= A+/- B, D = B and E = 0

And, if A=(100) & B=(250), then C=(350), D=(350) and E=0

And, if A=0 & B=(250), then C=(250), D=(250) and E=0

I cannot get the answer to appreciate that C and A cannot be greater than zero, and then when C hits zero, the whole of B shows in E and nothing shows in D.

My lack of advanced formulae knowledge is the limiting factor here, and without writing a hideously long and error-prone formula, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any constructive ideas would be hugely welcomed.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C:

```
=MIN(0,A1+B1)
```

In D

```
=MIN(ABS(A1),B1-ABS(A1))
```

In E

```
=MAX(0,B1-ABS(D1))
```

[image]